# TYPO3 - TransportException in Syslog?

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to get TransportException (form canot send mail due to invalid configuration of mail) into the syslog?

I´ve tried to set belogErrorReporting to "32767" (all), but error doesn´t show up.

Background: the hoster messed up some dns stuff and the transport_smtp_server wasn´t reachable. So error when sending a contactform. The error showed up in the error log, but not in the syslog in the backend.

Goal: simple way to see, if mailing is working or see if any problems occur.

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Maybe, you can use the Logging API... TransportException is thrown at different places of the core, some of them are catching the exception and calling the logger... So, you could configure the Logger of the relevant class to log into syslog.